# Need tool to parse numbers from webpages regularly and record store the values

Tags: parsing, web-applications

I have some research work in which data gets posted on a webpage in a standardised fashion, data which gets updated every 5 or so seconds, and I want to parse this data to read a value ..

For example, suppose at a given time, the webpage I'm trying to monitor has this text on it:

Field 1: 5
Field 2: 43
Field 3: 49
Field 4: 92
Field 5: 28
Field 6: 35

Now, the webpage will ALWAYS have the same number of fields, same formatting, etc .. The ONLY thing changing would be the values coming after the colon signs ..

I need a software/tool which when I give the URL of this webpage I want to observe, which can then parse this webpage's contents, and then start monitoring the value I tell it to monitor (e.g. for example the Field 4 value) ... And also, this software starts storing the values its sees in a text file or something, in which it also stores the time/data at which this value was observed ..

I intend to then plot this data so that I can see the trend of the number for different moments in time ..

I've never really done and web based coding, so I don't really know how to make a custom app which can do this ... Any software currently available which I can use guys ?

Comment: Thanks, thats the term alright .. looking for an easy to use software right now .. Do let me know if you know of any good web scraping software ... And I just forget to vote for the best answer .. Will try harder :)